# How to access Synchronized Data Extensions of marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud

In our marketing cloud platform, we have synchronized salesforce contact object into Synchronized Data Extensions folder. Now I wanna retrieve the object named 'Contact_Salesforce_1' by SOAP api, but I got the following error response:

```
<RetrieveResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
     <OverallStatus>Error: Invalid object name 'C100015214.Contact_Salesforce_1'.</OverallStatus>
     <RequestID>1464e09d-3020-4444-838c-f0c3b3d65630</RequestID>
</RetrieveResponseMsg>
```

My request is:

```
   <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
      <RetrieveRequest>
         <ObjectType>DataExtensionObject[Contact_Salesforce_1]</ObjectType>
         <Properties>Name</Properties>
      </RetrieveRequest>
   </RetrieveRequestMsg>
```

Why do I get this error? How can I fix it?

Comment: Hi Yiyun, welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to scroll through the [tour] and read [ask]. I modified your question here because you asked a question to which the answer would not be very useful (who can help you), and instead your post now asks a question to which the answer will help you (what is the cause of the error and how can it be reesolved). There are some great MC experts on here, so hopefully one of them can help you.

Answer (score 5):

Sync DE are "Owned" by the EID and not the child bu, since it appears you are using multiorg, I'm guessing you are not making this call with a token or un/pw (with default BU as EID) the belongs to the EID. To solve your issue you should use the `ClientID` node in the [SOAP call](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/using_clientid_in_your_soap_api_code.htm) or use a token that belongs to the EID

```
<Client> 
<ID>EID</ID> 
</Client>
```

Comment: Sorry, do you mean that MID IS EID? I`m using Username and Password for logging.
I modified my xml as follows:
  <soapenv:Header>
      // username & password
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
    <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
    <RetrieveRequest>
    <ObjectType>DataExtensionObject[Contact_Salesforce_1]</ObjectType>
   <ClientIDs>
    <ClientID>100015214</ClientID>
   </ClientIDs>
    <Properties>Name</Properties>
    </RetrieveRequest>
    </RetrieveRequestMsg>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
But the error is still be.

Answer (score 0):

By searching for documents and varied tries, I'm sure that the Synchronized Data Extensions can't be accessed totally. It is just like a pool that is used to store those records synchronized from salesforce platform. If you'd like to use them, you've to filter out the records what you need to a DE, then you can use SOAP/REST API to handle the DE.